# How to convert or cast Partial<T> to T

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a variable `Partial<T>` in my code.

```
returnPartial(): Partial<T> {}

proceed(param T) {} //<-- the input param is always type of T here, can not change that

let obj = this.returnPartial();
this.proceed(obj) //<-- error Argument of type 'Partial<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

In some instance `obj` variable is actually equal to `T` (by the shape). So I want to convert/cast that in to `T` to pass that to another function. How would you do that?

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261190/convert-object-of-a-partial-interface-type-to-the-full-interface-type-in-types

Answer (score 2):

The as keyword will tell the compiler to assert the object as another type

`this.proceed(obj as T)`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Adrian Brand correct answer, here are the two different syntax you can use to cast values :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL665gCeADigELIAvMgAKcKGGBwANgB4M6AHzNcCdCBrIARpQHC8hIqQrIA5GExhTAGlYqYAVxAJJ65DAAUAfUoKAlDjIbLie8piKWn7MnlrIcFRomFEhHpEquEA)

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
}

type B = Partial<Foo>;

const b: B = {
    name: 'toot',
};

function f(_: Foo) { }

// Syntax #1
f(<Foo>b);

// Syntax #2
f(b as Foo);


f(b);
```